# Basic array based, unable to access arrays element?

Tags: c, pointers

Hi Friends, 
            I am new to C. I am trying to learn it, I got stuck some where in arrays. Please check following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int arr1[] = {10,20,30,40,50};
int arr2[] = {5,15,25,35,45};

int *main_arr[] = {arr1,arr2};

int main()
{
 printf("in first array 0th locatin value is: %d\n",*main_arr[0]);
 system("PAUSE");   
 return 0;
}
```

By using printf i can print the value at 0th location, but not getting how to access rest of the element ...please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
...: %d\n",(main_arr[0])[0]);
           -------------      ->arr1
                        ---   ->arr1[0]
```

`main_arr` is pointing to both arrays `arr1`, `arr2`. So `main_arr[0]` points to the first element of the first array. To access other elements modify the 2nd `[0]`.

[Check it out](http://liveworkspace.org/code/c4pXv%241)

The other alternative, uglier but closer to your current code, is to use pointer arithmetic.

```
...s: %d\n",*(main_arr[0]+1));
```

Remember that `arr[1]` is the same as `*(arr+1)`.

Comment: Thanks for you quick reply ...can you please explain me how is it working....thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int arr1[] = {10,20,30,40,50};
int arr2[] = {5,15,25,35,45};

int *main_arr[] = {arr1,arr2};

int main()
{
 int iter1, iter2;
 for(iter1 = 0; iter1 < 2; iter1++){
    for(iter2 = 0; iter2 < 5; iter2++){
        printf("in first array nth locatin value is: %d\n",(main_arr[iter1][iter2]));
    }
 }
 system("PAUSE");   
 return 0;
}
```

I guess the code is simple enough to be understood?

Answer (score 0):

There are only two pointers in the main_arr, pointing to address of arr1 and arr2.

```
main_arr| ptr to an array | -> arr1
        | ptr to an array | -> arr2
```

So you can use `main_arr[0][1]` to access the second element of `arr1`, because `main_arr[0]` points to the address of the very first element of arr1.

You should have know that in C, if p is a pointer, then both `p[3]` and `3[p]` will evaluate to `*(p + 3 * sizeof(type))`, so let's assume `p = main_arr[0]`, then `p[1]`, which is `main_arr[0][1]`, will evaluate to `*(main_arr[0] + 1 * sizeof(int))`, which is the same value with `arr1[1]`.